# jQuery Plugin Namespace

Tags: jquery

How do I create a jQuery plugin so that I can use namespaces in my plugin ?

```
$("#id1").amtec.foo1();
$("#id1").amtec.foo2();
```

None  of these seem to work.

```
(function($) {
    var amtec = {
        $.fn.foo1 : function(){ return this.each(function(){}); },
        $.fn.foo2 : function(){ return this.each(function(){}); }
        };

    })(jQuery);
```

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.amtec = function(){
        var foo1 = function(){ return this.each(function(){}); };
        var foo2 = function(){ return this.each(function(){}); };
        }
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: would you please check out my solution. it's more accurate to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.amtec = function () {
        var jq = this;
        return {
            foo1: function(){
                return jq.each(function(){});
            },

            foo2: function(){
                return jq.each(function(){});
           }
       }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Alexander, error console in FireBug shows :
this.each is not a function

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexandar ! It does work but as 
$("#id1").amtec().foo1();
and not as
$("#id1").amtec.foo2();

Comment: well, I guess it's inevitable - because you need to preserve the `this` reference, and you cannot get it within an instantiated object.

Comment: You just saved my day!

Comment: the problem with this approach is, when you add a lot of methods in this way, then the namespace method return a very big object!
this isn't really creating namespace, just a quick dirty solution!

Answer (score 16):

I know I'm almost three years late to the party, but hopefully future readers of this question can benefit from my answer. The answer by [GSto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89761/gsto) looks great from a jQuery plugin design standpoint, but has one small issue: calling `mynamespace()` clobbers the returned jQuery instance with new methods. Here is an example of that being an issue:

```
$myDiv = $('.mydiv');
$myDiv.mynamespace().height(); // this will be `height' from mynamespace
$myDiv.height();               // this will STILL be `height' from mynamespace
                               //   because it has overwritten $myDiv.height
```

The chosen answer does not have this issue because there `amtec()` is not a jQuery instance and is instead an object that calls its methods with the jQuery instance as context. I have taken concepts from both answers and written the namespace plugin below:

```
(function($) {
  $.namespace = function(namespaceName, closures) {

    if ($.fn[namespaceName] === undefined) {
      $.fn[namespaceName] = function executor(context) {
        if (this instanceof executor) {
          this.__context__ = context;
        }
        else {
          return new executor(this);
        }
      };
    }

    $.each(closures, function(closureName, closure) {
      $.fn[namespaceName].prototype[closureName] = function() {
        return closure.apply(this.__context__, arguments);
      };
    });

  };
})(jQuery);
```

Example usage:

```
$.namespace('milosz', {
    redify: function() {
        $(this).css('color', '#ff0000');
    },
    greenify: function() {
        $(this).css('color', '#00ff00');
    }
});

$.namespace('milosz', {
    blueify: function() {
        $(this).css('color', '#0000ff');
    }
});

$('.mydiv').milosz().redify(); // The HTML elements with class `mydiv' are now red
```

The code uses some pretty low-level details of JavaScript that are well-explained by [John Resig's Advanced JavaScript tutorial](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/), but loosely speaking what is happening in the example is this:

When `milosz` (internally `$.fn[namespaceName]`) is called, `this` points to the `jQuery` instance returned by `$('.mydiv')`. Hence, the `if` statement falls through to the `else` block and the constructor version of `milosz` is called (referred-to internally as `executor` for reasons that are about to become apparent). The constructor is passed a single parameter: `this`, a pointer to the `jQuery` the instance that is going to be the execution context for all members of the `milosz` namespace. We enter back into the `if` statement, this time executing the first block, wherein the passed-in `jQuery` instance is stored in a member variable called `__context__` (which hopefully has a low chance of being overwritten). The constructed object is returned, complete with a reference to the original `jQuery` instance and any wrappers added to its prototype by invocations of `$.namespace`. These wrappers simply execute the methods passed into the `milosz` namespace with the original `jQuery` object as context, as happens when `redify` is executed.

Bah, I know it's a mouthful, anyway the point is it works like the accepted answer but looks like the jQueryish answer, which to me is the best of both worlds.

Comment: Great approach, thanks from a year after, three years after the party.

Comment: I will be using this technique in my new jQuery plugin factory library.  Makes my head hurt, but it works!

Comment: I know it has been a while, but this method doesn't allow me to call a function as $.myNamespace().function() - but it works as $().myNamespace().function() - anybody have a solution to this?

Comment: @NickBarone, that is a solution to a different problem. Here we specifically wanted to give namespaces to jQuery *instances*, not to the jQuery object itself. I believe if you simply replace all instances of `$.fn` in the above code with `$` you will have what you need. However, if you don't need the namespace to be a function you can simply do `$.myNamespace = {}; $.myNamespace.func = function() { return 'bar'; };` to get a "namespace" effect.

Comment: how can I return values from the methods invoked in the plugin? it returns undefined to me http://jsfiddle.net/h86brjrn/

Comment: Mahan, good call! I was missing a "return". Updated answer and fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h86brjrn/1/

Answer (score 3):

```
(function($){
  $.namespace = function(ns, functions){
    $.fn[ns] = function() {return this.extend(functions)};
  };
  $.namespace('$', $.fn); // the default namespace
})(jQuery);
```

So now you can have a plugin:

```
$.fn.func = function(){alert('plugin'); return this'};
```

and create plugins in a namespace:

```
$.namespace ('mynamespace', {
  func: function() {alert('namespaced plugin'); return this;},
  otherfunc: function() {return this.css('color', 'yellow');}
});
```

And if you do

```
$('div').func(); // alerts 'plugin' -- no namespace
```

But

```
$('div').mynamespace().func(); // alerts 'namespaced plugin'
```

And

```
$('div').mynamespace().func().$().func(); // alerts 'namespaced
```

plugin', then resets to the normal jquery and alerts 'plugin'

Comment: To call otherFunc would it jsut be $(div).mynamespace.otherFunc(); ?

Comment: Be careful with this. Clever answer but behaves more like the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) than a Namespace.  That could could get you into trouble if you're not familiar with the usual pros & cons of that pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question... But why write all this extra code when you can just replace `.` with `_`?

```
$.fn.amtec_foo1 = function(){ return this.each(function(){}); }
$.fn.amtec_foo2 = function(){ return this.each(function(){}); }
```

Better yet, give your plugin a name that's original & project agnostic.

```
$.fn.fooize = function(){ return this.html('Element has been Fooized!'); }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.cg = {
  foo1: function(weq){
      return console.log(weq);
  },
  foo2: function(rw){
      return console.log(rw);
 }
}; 
$.cg = { // will result in error because $.cg is already declared above

  foo4: function(rw){ // will result in error
      return console.log(rw); // will result in error
 } // will result in error
}; // will result in error

$.cg.foo3 = function(weq){ //to add anything new to $.cg , you have to do it this way.
      return console.log(weq);
  }

$.cg.foo1("12");
$.cg.foo2("22"); //works fine.
$.cg.foo3("112"); //works fine.
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the functions will not receive the jQuery selector inside the `this` context.