# Preventing conflict between jquery prototype/plugin methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, conflicting-libraries

Suppose i have a main js file on the website that contains some code as follows:

```
$.fn.extend({
  break: function(){
    //code here
  },
  cut: function(){
   //code here
  },
  // ...many other methods
});
```

and i use it like so:

```
$('#mydiv').break().animate() ...
```

Now if i add an external jquery plugin file that also has a 'break' method, how do i prevent conflict between my $.fn methods and someone else's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

This is why many plugins, such as jQuery UI, only add a single method to the prototype which takes an action name as a parameter.

Comment: Just came accross this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537848/jquery-plugin-namespace 
I havent tried this yet but is it close to what i am looking for? Will it work if i place 'break' and 'cut' methods within '$.fn.myNamespace' ?

Comment: Yes, that will also work.  However, I've never seen a real plugin that does that.