# From where can all keywords of jquery

Tags: jquery

I am searching list of All reserved Keywords of jquery so that I can know which keyword is used where.

Comment: If you are trying to create custom jquery plugin and worried about name conflicts, I suggest you to use namespaces. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537848/jquery-plugin-namespace & http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: Thanks for your response, I want to list of all keywords of jquery, just like if want to  search list of all keywords of C#, I can get all keywords at a place. I want to program simple jquery in my application, but I am not aware of all taga, keywords of jquery

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses only two global identifiers; `$` and `jQuery`.

For a list of all jQuery methods and properties, see http://api.jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

Here you will get whatever you want: **[JQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/)**

These are some of them:

```
break    export    return
case     for       switch
comment  function  this
continue if        typeof
default  import    var
delete   in        void
do       label     while
else     new       with
```